# ¿Como combinar dos listas en python obteniendo datos específicos de cada y guardarlos en una nueva lista?

Tags: python, json

Mi duda es si podría yo de dos listas obtener una nueva con datos específicos de cada una, por ejemplo:

```
{  
    "id": "1",
    "profesor":"PA",
    "nombre":"christian baladimir",
    "asignaturas":["Redes", "Algebra lineal"],
    "horas": "15",
    "disponibilidad":
        [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
}
```

y fusionarla con esta lista:

```
    {
    "id":["Qu1","Qui2","Qui3"],
    "nombre":"Quimica",
    "grado":1,
    "horas_semana":4,
    "grupo": [1,2,3]
}
```

Y por medio de esas dos listas obtener una nueva con datos de la primera como el nombre del profesor y sus asignaturas y de la segunda obtener el id, y el nombre teniendo una salida mas o menos como esta:

```
{"profesor": "Christian", "asignaturas": "Redes", ""id":["Qu1","Qui2","Qui3"], "nombre":"Quimica"}
```

Comment: Lo primero, eso son `dicts`, no listas. Una vez aclarado eso, sí, es posible hacerlo y es bastante sencillo. ¿Podrías decir qué has probado a hacer?

Comment: @Saelyth hola, ya he intentado con comb y set y no he tenido éxito tal vez lo he hecho mal. Espero me puedas dar alguna pista o ayuda para poder guiarme en esta duda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al ser datos específicos, es tan fácil como conocer la `key` de cada diccionario, que por suerte conocemos (profesor, nombre, etc).

```
datos_de_profe = {
"id": "1",
"profesor":"PA",
"nombre":"christian baladimir",
"asignaturas":["Redes", "Algebra lineal"],
"horas": "15"}

datos_de_asignatura = {
"id":["Qu1","Qui2","Qui3"],
"nombre":"Quimica",
"grado":1,
"horas_semana":4,
"grupo": [1,2,3]}
```

Por tanto, simplemente creamos un nuevo diccionario accediendo a los valores de las `keys` de los diccionarios anteriores, de la siguiente manera:

```
nuevo_dict = {"profesor":datos_de_profe['profesor'], "asignaturas":datos_de_profe['asignaturas'], "id":datos_de_asignatura['id'], "nombre":datos_de_asignatura['nombre']}
```

El resultado sería:

```
{'profesor': 'PA', 'asignaturas': ['Redes', 'Algebra lineal'], 'id': ['Qu1', 'Qui2', 'Qui3'], 'nombre': 'Quimica'}
```

Creo que te ayudaría entender como acceder a estructuras de datos, en tu caso la sección 5.5: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html